# How to extend width of the container in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the `.container` class in my navbar, body, and footer.

So all three align well on the left. However, I would like to increase the width of the `container` class.

By default the width is coming at 1170:

```
media="screen, projection"
bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css:6139@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 1170px;
}
```

However, I would like to extend the width to 1300. So I added the following in my `main.css`

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I reload the page and inspect the CSS, the 1200 is crossed out and 1170 is still active.

**Question**

How can I extend the default width of the `container` class in bootstrap?

Comment: Try adding !important after your width statement, so it becomes: `width: 1200px !important;`

Comment: @StefanCandan that is a very bad practice. You should very rarely use that

Comment: @CodyGuldner - I disagree. Well, I agree, but you should explain more before advising not to use it. It's an extremlely useful declaration for doing just this; overwriting styles written or hosted by third-parties. How else are you supposed to overwrite CSS styles when you're loading from a CDN or a JS file is adding inline styles which need to be overwritten. It's bad practice using it on your own code, as it's better to fix than to hack, but in this case, using that declaration is the only viable option for some, and a good one. Don't use it unless you know how to, is much better advice.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are loading or `main.css` (`bootstrap.css`), and making your changes there.  Then you are probably calling `bootstrap-responsive.css` after that and it is overwriting your changes.

The 1170px `.container` width comes from the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file.  It is the width assigned by default to Large Display screens (1200px and wider).  That is why I am assuming you are calling `bootstrap-responsive.css` after your `main.css` file.

Using `!important` is an anti-pattern (a bad practice) in this regard.  Especially on something as generic as your `.container`.  This will lead to specificity issues in the future. I encourage you to actually fix and understand the problem, instead of "hacking it".

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

> !important can be used in cascading style sheets to give priority to
>   parameters

```
.container {
   width: 1200px !important;
 }
```

Check [this](http://www.yellowjug.com/web-design/the-importance-of-important-in-css/) for more information.

> For this case !important can be used as work around, but using this property is
>   considered as a bad practise and is not recommended by CSS experts.

Comment: This is a bad practice that should be avoided at all costs

Comment: I don't think this should be down-voted just due to bad practice, it does indeed solve the users issue. He has also updated the answer noting that it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, however I was recently searching on how to expand the container width on the newest version of bootstrap (3.0) and thought this may help others.

Asides from setting a width for the container you must also set a max-width property to your css.

```
container 
{
  width:1200px;
  max-width:1200px;
}
```

As others have noted above, make sure to load your custom css after the bootstrap.css file so the settings are re declared.

Answer (score 0):

In case, you're using bootstrap scss.

file: `_variables.scss`

add breakpoint (here xxl: 1440px) for your bigger container width.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;
```

create bigger container by just adding xxl: 1200px

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1200px
) !default;
```

Bootstrap mixins will create extra breakpoint media query for 1200px wide container.

For more on changing bootstrap variable please go to [Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/)